# Fourier transform, how should I solve there one?

Tags: fourier-transform

I can't figure out how to solve this problem, could anyone help me?

**Find the Fourier transform of 
F(x) = { sin(x), if |x| <= pi and 0(null) if, |x| > pi }**

*edit: I got stuck on the following integral

[image: integral]

Please, explain if it's possible
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible... You need to explain where you're having trouble. For instance do you know the definition of a fourier transform? (And for that matter, which of the several definitions are you using?) Can you write down the integral you're trying to do and explain what about it makes it difficult?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset mathematical expressions in your posts and also edit to include your attempt on solving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The Fourier transform is defined as

$$ F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ist} f(t) \ dt $$

As $f$ is piecewise defined, you have really one integral to deal with:

$$ F(s) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-ist} \sin t \ dt $$

Now you have two options: write $e^{-ist}$ in terms of sines and cosines, or use a nice even-odd trick. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, i got on the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rectangle function multiplied by a sine wave. So, to get the ft, you can convolve the fourier transform of the rectangle (a sinc function) with the fourier transform of the sine wave (a sum of 2 delta functions) and use the delta function's sifting property to gettheresult.